# How can I see the list of the most viewed question ever?

Tags: support

In case I am missing it or it is biting me in the face, is there a way I can view the list of the:

- most viewed question
- most voted question
- most answered question

I`m looking for an all time span not the monthly option we have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most viewed question: Choose [Questions, then Frequent](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent). That's the all time list ordered by number of views.

Most voted question: [Questions, then Votes](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). This gives you the all time by votes list.

There isn't a view of questions by number of answers, but many of the most viewed and most voted questions have a lot of answers.

Comment: Thank you! Still learning the ropes of this place.

Comment: You can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for most answered questions. I made you a query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/sqa/revision/710301/884065/most-answered-questions-10

Answer (score 0):

This should be under Meta, but the Question there was closed:

[View Most Popular Questions by favorite count / views / votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29405/view-most-popular-questions-by-favorite-count-views-votes)

This answer by Ambo100 is more detailed, but the query is also more complex: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252164/382589

The answer below was adapted from the comment from Aquarius Power.

```
select top 20 Id as [Post Link], ViewCount
from Posts
order by ViewCount desc
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1382098/most-viewed-posts

Just edit the 'stackoverflow' in the URL to whatever site you want to search, like below:

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1382098/most-viewed-posts

All SE sites sorted by traffic (visits/day) for reference:

https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic

Answer (score 0):

Can also search for views:400000 for example, to see all questions with lots of views.

Example:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=views%3A400000

shows (at time of writing) the top viewed question.